# How can I attach all images file in directory using MIME

Tags: python, image, email, mime-types, mime

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
import os

project_name = "ถังเก็บน้ำดับเพลิง 350m3 บีพี"
notwearing = 5
output_paths ='/Users/khemakorn/Downloads/export_files/pk98_ปรับปรุงฝ้าและผนังโรงอาหาร โรงชำแหละสุกร พนมทวน กาญจนบุรี'


do_not_reply ="****DO NOT REPLY THIS EMAIL****"
# messages = project_name+" "+str(notwearing)+" ครั้ง\n\n\n"
mail_content = """ตรวจพบผู้ไม่สวมหมวกนิรภัยในโครงการ """+project_name+""" จำนวน """+str(notwearing)+""" ครั้ง \n\n\n\n"""+do_not_reply
#The mail addresses and password
sender_address = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'
sender_pass = 'xxxxx'
receiver_address = ['xxxxxxx@mail.xxxx.ac.th','xxxxxx@icloud.com']
#Setup the MIME
message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['To'] = ','.join(receiver_address)
message['Subject'] = 'TESTTEST'   #The subject line
#The body and the attachments for the mail
message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
fp = open('k.png', 'rb')
msgImage2 = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
# msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image2>')
message.attach(msgImage2)
#Create SMTP session for sending the mail
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) #use gmail with port
session.starttls() #enable security
session.login(sender_address, sender_pass) #login with mail_id and password
text = message.as_string()
session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
session.quit()
print('Mail Sent')
```

Now it can send only the picture in the same directory of the code
but I want it to send all image files in 'output_paths' how can I do it.
I did try some for loop as the example on the internet but it didn't even work for running

Answer (score 0):

```
sending_path = glob.glob(output_paths+"/*")
random.shuffle(sending_path)
for img_path in sending_path:

    fp = open(img_path, 'rb')
    msgImage2 = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    message.attach(msgImage2)
```

done